# Need help translating artist seal

Tags: translation

[image]

I am trying to get a translation on the seal to determine the artist's name. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it is not a translation problem, it is a recognition problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess.

马驷

馬駟 in traditional Chinese

[more for 駟](http://www.zdic.net/z/28/js/9A77.htm)

[image]